# Script works only on local machine

Tags: powershell

I've done the following script but it won't work, (I'm a complete new to powershell) it must run as a ps1 file format.

```
Stop-process -Name *******
Rename-Item -Path "C:\*\*.lbr" -NewName "old-*.lbr" 
Copy-Item \\*.*.*.*\Folder\R_Update\refunds -Recurse C:\*\
C:\*\refunds\setup.exe /quiet
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
msiexec.exe /i C:\*\refunds\*.msi /qn
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
Copy-Item -Path C:\*\refunds\*.lbr -Destination C:\*\
```

( it works on the local machine but not a networked one)
Please help

Comment: Please, format your message, especially code part. For your problem, I think you can use SCCM or GPO to run script on every machine in your local network.

Comment: errors getting back are

Comment: What kind of errors? Can you add them to the comment?

Comment: One of the errors which the report comes back is :- Process must exit before requested information can be determined. <- what ever that means

Comment: Can you trace step-by-step your code? Before every line add `Write-Output "Step 1...8"`. This will help us to determine where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Alex R,   I've found my problem,   No set permission on remote machine also , someone moved the folder which needed to be transfered remotely

Comment: Regarding the error, it has come back with a different error now   `code`Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\*.*.*.*\e$\Branch FTP\Upgrades\refunds' because it does not exist. At C:\Program Files\ATERA Networks\AteraAgent\Packages\AgentPackageSystemTools\c6ed81bc-2a51-4d2d-837e-8b351cee608f_newer.ps1:5 char:1
+ Copy-Item '\\*.*.*.*\e$\Branch FTP\Upgrades\refunds' -Destination .+     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\*.*.*.*\e...pgrades\refunds:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand